# Is salary verification legal in the UK?

Tags: salary, job-offer, united-kingdom

**Can a prospective employer in the UK ask me to prove the salary history I gave them?**

I have recently secured an offer with one the fintech companies (well-known, well-respected) in London, UK. We are currently negotiating about the details (I have declined their initial offer), and the HR department wants me to provide some evidence of previous employment history (more specifically, previous offers mentioning base salary and various bonuses). I have disclosed this information before my final interview (with the intention that it would help the company to produce a good offer), but now they are requesting some 'confirmation' (copied or scanned) for the numbers that I mentioned. While I have rather positive impression about the company after the interviews and rather interested to accept the offer, provided we agree on details, I do feel that the HR are asking for too much. I am working overseas and such requests seem rather odd to me. **Can they legally ask me for proof of past salary?**

Comment: Seems fishy I have never had to provide proof - maybe they have foreign management or hr who don't understand the UK or negotiation.

Comment: If you mention an offer or any number then yes they can ask for confirmation.

Comment: I've cut your question down to the essentials. As discussed on meta, general legal questions like this are on-topic on the site.

Comment: Bizarrely I've found very little info on this. Since the UK.gov sites don't mention anything about this under the "questions you can't ask" section or list it as protected info, I assume the answer is "yes they can ask" but it would be better to get some other source to confirm this.

Comment: Not quite the same as providing evidence of other offers, but I believe your current salary would be provided on the P45 you would supply when you started.

Comment: @Paparazzi source for that claim?

Comment: Voting to close as asking specifically about legality so off topic.  I've never seen any laws prohibiting asking for verification in the UK, or even that salary is kept secret from co-workers, but I've seen companies who have opinions on both.

Comment: @JamesWebster - Not exactly... any salary sacrifice (e.g. for pension or additional unpaid leave) would reduce the apparent salary that could be extrapolated from a P45. Also, any bonuses that would occur (but haven't due to leaving before payment date) wouldn't be reflected either. Plus you don't *have* to give your P45 to your new employer, you can just get put on a Month 1 tax code instead.

Comment: Someone from South Africa, by chance, where it is usual to ask for that data?Tell them to get lost.

Answer (score 3):

This is unusual because it is personal data which is protected by the Data Protection Act. So, they can ask, but you're not obliged to comply.

> Personal data, however, is usually more general and includes information on salary and previous jobs.

From [Avoid breaching the Data Protection Act](http://www.personneltoday.com/hr/avoid-breaching-the-data-protection-act/)

As an aside, I'm from the UK and have applied for fintech and big bank jobs before. At no point was I asked to provide evidence of my salary history. I was asked to provide my previous/current salary on application, but I safely got away with writing '*I will not disclose salary information*'.